# SQLiteException: no such column

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Here's what I want to do

If a person types in "Gggfggvgvvvvvvvvvvv" or whatever that name isn't in the database so I'm attempting to return a message to the user along the lines of "username does not exist".

Here's my problem. When a user clicks the "getDetails" button I'm getting a nasty error message (error message below).

Here's what I thought would work but it's not working. Since getColumnIndex equals -1 if the column does not exist I figured I would compare the index1 to -1. If that comparison is true I would Toast a message to my user but I'm getting a error message.

My question is, how would I fix this problem? How would I get my syntax to Toast a message to the user without my app crashing?

```
public void getDetails(View view){
   String theName = name.getText().toString();
   insertHelper.checkToSeeIfUserNameExist(theName);
}

public void checkToSeeIfUserNameExist(String theUserName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] selectColoumnsFromDatabase = {
        InsertDatabaseHelper.NAME   
    };

    String selectionArgs= theUserName;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            InsertDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, 
            selectColoumnsFromDatabase, 
            selectionArgs,  
            null, null, null, null
            );
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(InsertDatabaseHelper.NAME);

        if(index1 == -1){
            SQLMessage.message(helper.context, "Username Does Not Exist");
        } else {
            SQLMessage.message(helper.context, "Something Else Is Happening");
        }

    }
}


06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9081)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:870)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     ... 11 more
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Gggfggvgvvvvvvvvvvv: , while compiling: SELECT Name FROM SHANETABLE WHERE Gggfggvgvvvvvvvvvvv
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1235)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1189)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1271)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at com.example.multapps.InsertDatabaseAdapter.checkToSeeIfUserNameExist(InsertDatabaseAdapter.java:152)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     at com.example.multapps.InsertIntoDatabase.getDetails(InsertIntoDatabase.java:61)
06-28 15:04:20.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2999):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain the cursor correctly:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(InsertDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,                  // table
                         new String[] { InsertDatabaseHelper.NAME },       // columns
                         InsertDatabaseHelper.NAME + " = ? ",              // selection
                         new String[] { theUserName },                     // selectionArgs
                         null, null, null);                                // unused
```

You're not checking the cursor that you get back properly by just calling `moveToNext()`. 
If no matching rows are returned it will return false so your code won't run.
Checking what's in the Cursor is better done via:

```
try {
    if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst()) { //moveToFirst returns false if cursor is empty!
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Username exists!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Username doesn't exist!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} finally { // ensures that your cursor is closed no matter what!
    if (null != cursor) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

You could also check how many rows are in the cursor via `cursor.getCount()`

Comment: Thanks, my SQL statement wasn't working. That was the culprit. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Here's your error:

```
while compiling: SELECT Name FROM SHANETABLE WHERE Gggfggvgvvvvvvvvvvv
```

Your query should look something like:

```
SELECT Name FROM SHANETABLE WHERE Name = 'Gggfggvgvvvvvvvvvvv'
```

Then, if the cursor has **0 rows**, that name doesn't exist in your table.

Comment: Thanks, my SQL statement wasn't working. That was t he culprit. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally have a column for a given username.  Generally you have a column called "username" which has a value for each row.  Either your schema is really weird or you confused the columns themselves with the values in the columns.